# pip install using tarball archive from private gitlab repo using authentication

Tags: pip, gitlab

I'm trying to install a python module from a compressed archive URL which is a gitlab private repo URL. But it is throwing error:

```
pip install https://gitlab.com/<myprivate_repo_path>/-/archive/main/private-module.tar.gz

Collecting https://gitlab.com/<myprivate_repo_path>/-/archive/main/private-module.tar.gz
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gitlab.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /users/sign_in (Caused by ResponseError('too many 503 error responses'))
```

Though installing from the compressed archive from a public repo works fine:

```
pip install https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/archive/3.7.7/flake8-3.7.7.tar.gz
Collecting https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/archive/3.7.7/flake8-3.7.7.tar.gz
  Downloading https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/archive/3.7.7/flake8-3.7.7.tar.gz
     | 153 kB 328 kB/s
Collecting entrypoints<0.4.0,>=0.3.0
  Downloading entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pyflakes<2.2.0,>=2.1.0
  Downloading pyflakes-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 59 kB 476 kB/s 
Collecting pycodestyle<2.6.0,>=2.5.0
  Downloading pycodestyle-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51 kB 782 kB/s 
Collecting mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Downloading mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for flake8, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyflakes, pycodestyle, mccabe, entrypoints, flake8
    Running setup.py install for flake8 ... done
Successfully installed entrypoints-0.3 flake8-3.7.7 mccabe-0.6.1 pycodestyle-2.5.0 pyflakes-2.1.1
```

**Is there any way I can still `pip install` from a private repo by giving a compressed archive URL?**

**I've already tried this:**

1. Created a token in GitLab by following [this URL](https://www.kisphp.com/python/pip-install-from-private-gitlab-repository)
2. Used that token in the URL:

   ```
   pip install https://<user>:<pass>@gitlab.com/<myprivate_repo_path>/-/archive/main/private-module.tar.gz
   ```

But it resulted in the same error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='gitlab.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /users/sign_in (Caused by ResponseError('too many 503 error responses'))
```

**Note:**

**I'm not looking for something like below,** as it adds extra dependency of having git to be installed (especially when using docker) + My requirement is to install the module from a compressed archive.

```
pip install git+https://<user>:<pass>@gitlab.com/<myprivate_repo_path>/private-module.git
```

Answer (score 0):

### Authenticating to GitLab

Your initial problem is that you can't authenticate with username and password using basic auth to the get archive that's shown in the UI for a private repo. GitLab does not support basic auth like that.

Instead, you should use the GitLab API and authenticate that way using an API token. You can use the [repository file archive API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive) to get the same tarball archive using the API, which will support proper authentication.

Using curl as an example

```sh
curl -o mypackage.tar.gz --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive"
pip install ./mypackage.tar.gz
rm ./mypackage.tar.gz
```

### Use a GitLab PyPI repository

[PyPI repositories](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/) are also a supported feature of GitLab in all tiers. You could leverage that feature and just use [regular authentication methods for PyPI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/#authenticate-with-a-ci-job-token) with your token to pull the package from the private index.

### Avoiding unneeded dependencies in Docker

> it adds extra dependency of having git to be installed (especially when using docker)

As an additional note on this since you mentioned docker... if you're using docker, you can readily use multistage builds to avoid the dependency issue in your built image.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim as build

# install build-time dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install -y git
RUN pip install --upgrade wheel pip

# fetch and build dependencies to wheels
ARG USERNAME
ARG PASSWORD
WORKDIR /opt/build
RUN pip wheel -w wheelhouse "git+https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@gitlab.com/path/mypackage/repo.git"

FROM python:3.9-slim as final
# copy pre-built packages from build stage
COPY --from=build /opt/build/wheelhouse /wheelhouse
# install the package from wheels
RUN pip install --no-index --find-links /wheelhouse mypackage
```

This way, you only install git in the first stage, but it won't be present in the final built image. There's more that could be done to optimize this multistage build, but this is just a concise explanation of how to avoid the dependency issue you described.

Comment: I guess you're right. Passing auth header to download the packages feature is missing in pip. I may have not mentioned it earlier, but I wanted to put the archive URL in `requirements.txt`. Which I can't achieve when I use CURL. for example, simply adding this line in `requirement.txt` will install the module if the URL is from the public repo:

`https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/archive/3.7.7/flake8-3.7.7.tar.gz`

Comment: @SauravKumar on the header, yeah,  it's [not available in `pip`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8042) but if you're looking for a pure Python solution, you could still use `urllib.request` to download the tarball using the appropriate header, then just call `pip` on the downloaded file (similar to the steps in the answer using curl). You could even make a wrapper around `pip` to make it seamless. On issue of `requirements.txt` -- pip supports both environment variable substitution as well as installing local packages (and tarballs) specified in requirements files.

Comment: [PyPI repositories](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/) are also a supported feature of GitLab in all tiers... you could leverage that feature and just use regular authentication methods to the private index. So that option is available as well.

Comment: Yes gitlab supports package registry which can be achieved by adding a line something like this : `--index-url https://<user>:<token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple` in `requirements.txt`. But it requires all developers to follow gitlab instructions to setup in their local who are pushing to gitlab package register. Seems slightly extreme to me. I'm having a feeling that GitLab might be allowing to download files by passing auth in URL path like `https://<user>:<token>@gitlab.com/modulearchivepath` or in query params `?token=<token>` but not sure how.

Comment: @SauravKumar regarding use of header and `pip`, it is also possible to pass the token as a query parameter like `?private_token=<token>` See [api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/index.html) docs.